# How to use R to make sure an item is present in all 3 lists?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

We have three places were we keep our records for our mice cages' numbers in our lab:

1. Website for university where they bill us
2. Personal excel sheet
3. Website for our whole lab

I'm trying to organize them to make sure every entry is present in all three places and not missing from one of them.

Is there a way to give me which cage number is present in all three, and which is present in only one or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to know numbers that are present in all, `intersect` is good

```
Reduce(intersect, lst1)
```

where `lst1` is a `list` of three vectors.  To find the count of elements that are present, `unlist` the `list` elements and get the frequency count with `table`

```
table(unlist(lst1))
```

---

If we need to know which item is present or not, `stack` on a named `list` and get the `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(lst1, seq_along(lst1))))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Is there a way to find which item is present only in vector 1 or vector 2 or vector 3? or missing only in one of the three?

Comment: @AhmadEl-Hamamy try the update

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, appreciate it. I don't know how to accept a solution though, I'm new to the site.